# Best practice way to store countries and cities

Tags: categories

Is there a recommended way for storing countries and cities in craft?
I can see fields and categories as obvious options but its difficult to see the disadvantages/advantages of either at the beginning of a project.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on what you're actually trying to do, but if you're building this as part of a plugin, I'd store them as relational tables in the database, and display them as dropdown fields. If you provide more specific information about what you're building, I'll see if I can lend a hand.

Comment: Thanks Taylor. It will be a directory of sea ports. So I am planning geocoding, maps and a url structure like 'country/city/portname'. I was also keen on exploring the element API Brandon [https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI] to provide json ouput. It might be an ambitious first craft project but I am keen to dig in :)

Comment: If it were me, I'd just setup a [Route](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) that sends that URL to your template, then fetch related content with Craft's native entry functionality. And the ElementAPI is a fantastic (if a little ambitious) way to get into Craft!

Comment: A plugin sounds like overkill for a flexible CMS surely?

Comment: @joomkit Correct, from what you described in your previous comment I'd suggest simply using Routes, as I mentioned. (Routes are native Craft functionality.) Not sure about any other needs you might have, so YMMV.